# Having an issue setting a Variable as a $_GET value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Just getting to grips with SQL and PHP and trying to build a simple user account system - with a forgotten password email link.

I have a script below that I am trying to use to update the password of a user. They receive an email with a link. The link looks like this: `http://localhost:8887/email-password-reset.php?id=1`.

I know this is unsafe and easily hackable! I am planning on using a randomly generated string of numbers, once I get this working!

I am trying to user the `$_GET` function to get the `id`. However I don't believe that the `$_GET["id"]` is getting passed to the `$param_id` variable.

I'm new to this so unsure how to rectify it!

How can I get this set the param_id to the `$_GET` Value?

At least that what I think the issue is from the error in the console (`Undefined variable: param_id!)` Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
//session_start();
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$new_password = $confirm_password = "";
$new_password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
$param_id = ''; 

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate new password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["new_password"]))){
        $new_password_err = "Please enter the new password.";
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["new_password"])) < 6){
        $new_password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $new_password = trim($_POST["new_password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm the password.";
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($new_password_err) && ($new_password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before updating the database
    if(empty($new_password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_password, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $param_id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '');


            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Password updated successfully. Destroy the session, and redirect to login page
                session_destroy();
                header("location: login.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting and first check to see if the GET is set and not empty. You should also use `mysqli_error($link)` in the "Oops" instead when testing/developing.

Comment: Plus, you should be doing a SELECT in order to check if the user exists and that the GET corresponds to what was sent and matches. In a nutshell, you're doing it wrong. *Unless*, you didn't show us that code.

Comment: Ah ok - spent hours trying to figure out where I was going wrong. I think i'll have to think of another solution! Thought I maybe a syntax issue...wish-full thinking.

Comment: Well, maybe and maybe not. I'd start by first checking to see if the GET array is set and not empty as I said earlier, instead of having it where it is now. Then you'd use that value to update the database table with. It looks more like a logic issue here. I was wrong about the SELECT earlier. It's been a while since I worked on something like this *lol*.

Comment: There's another answer below; that looks promising. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Cursory glance:

It's only going into your `if` if it's a `POST` type, by definition it'll be a `GET` type.  You may need to remove/change that.

Secondly, you're building the query using `$param_id` before you assign `$param_id` to the `GET` variable.

If the only place, and it seems so, you're setting `$param_id` why not just declare it in the first line where you declare it as `''`?

Comment: Ok! When I put the GET into the variable at the top I still don't think its getting passed on into the if statement. It is however outside the if statement as I can echo it - if that makes sense!

Comment: Yes, because by putting a `GET` variable in, the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` is no longer `POST` so it's not getting into your `if` statement. If you're doing 2 things on this page, you may need to move the `GET` part either to an `else` or a new `if`.

Answer (score 0):

> They receive an email with a link. The link looks like this:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8887/email-password-reset.php?id=1
> ```

I assume if user click the link there will be a "new password" form. Then the form post the data to some url that contain the sciprt you use.
 To use `$_GET['id']` you need make sure the url on the form ( maybe looks like `action="http://localhost:8887/process.php"`) have GET parameter. So it's gonna looks like `action="http://localhost:8887/process.php?id=1"`
And the error `Undefined variable: param_id!` is because you use `param_id` before declare it. So, it's suppose looks like:

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

  // Set parameters
  $param_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $param_id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '');

  // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_password, $param_id);

  // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
  if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
     // Password updated successfully. Destroy the session, and redirect to login page
     session_destroy();
     header("location: login.php");
     exit();
  } else{
     echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Still having no luck though! Have you got any other suggestions?